# difference between yeoman-angular-fullstack and yeoman-meanjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meanjs

Can anyone please explain me the pros and cons of yeoman angular-fullstack and yeoman-meanjs.

I want to use MEAN stack for my project. please suggest me which one I could choose

Answer (score 0):

Within all the generators you can try angular-fullstack to create my MEAN project structure , reasons:

1.Easy to install

2. Creates both client and server scaffoldings
3. Introduces good practices in the generated code
4. Server side API prepared to use authentication
5. Support HTML or jade templating on client side
6. Support for different CSS preprocessors
7. Commands to scaffold anything

Detailed definition is [here](http://acuriousanimal.com/blog/2014/10/18/7-reasons-to-use-yeomans-angular-fullstack-generator/)

Comment: Thank you so much. I too had one through this advantages of angular- full stack. Does MEANjs stack not have this features.? what is the disadvantage of MEANJS stack

Comment: There is no such thing as MEAN.js, it's just an acronym for MongoDB, Express, Angular and NodeJS, so any disadvantages that any of those four have will surface as disadvantages in general.